# Ellie's hair disappeared. How do I get it back?

Tags: modeling, animation

I was working on a walk cycle with Blender Studio's Ellie rig, but something happened and suddenly all of the pieces of her hair are invisible. I pressed alt-H but that didn't change anything. I'm still pretty new to Blender so I'm really thrown for a loop here. How do I get the hair back?

[image]

File: [image]

original Ellie file I linked from: [image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sure, I just added it

Comment: I can't see any mesh, is it a linked object?

Comment: Yeah, I'll add the original file to the post. It's linked and overriden from ellie.blend, in Collections->CH Ellie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reactivate the visibility of the collection called *ellie.hair.mesh* and all its components, also there are some drivers for these elements, maybe deactivate them:

[image]